# I can't use pop()? javascript

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have a few constructor classes set up and I'm trying to pop this element. For some reason I can't. I can call it but I can't pop it and I'm not sure why. I'm posting full code (It's an uno game). I think it might have something to do with the fact that the player was invoked in a different constructor but I used a callback so I figure I should be able to alter it as I can do all the functions.

As an alternative I'll probably make a function inside Player that allows pop but I'd like some insight.

Halfway through this code is an uncoded line where I'm having the issue.

```
function Card(color, value){
  this.color = color
  this.value = value
  var values = {
    10: "Skip",  // 2 per color
    11: "Draw 2",  //2 per color
    12: "Reverse", //2 per color
    13: "Wild",  // 4 wilds
    14: "Wild Draw Four" //4 of these
  }
  var color = ["Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red"]
  if (values[this.value]){
    this.name = `${values[this.value]} of ${color[this.color]}`
  }
  else{
    this.name = `${this.value} of ${color[this.color]}`
  }
}
function Deck(){
  this.deck = []
  this.pile = []
  for (var color = 0; color < 4; color ++){
    for (var value = 0; value <= 14; value++){
      this.deck.push(new Card(color, value))
    }
  }
  for (var color = 0; color < 4; color ++){
    for (var value = 1; value <=12; value++){
      this.deck.push(new Card(color, value))
    }
  }
  this.shuffle = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i<this.deck.length; i++){
      var j = Math.floor(Math.random()*this.deck.length)
      var temp = this.deck[j]
      this.deck[j] = this.deck[i]
      this.deck[i] = temp
    }
  }
  }

function Player(hand, name, callname){
  this.hand = hand
  this.name = name
  this.callname = callname
}
function functioning_turns(players, my_deck){
  console.log(players);
  for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
    current = players[i]
    console.log(current);
    name_curr = players[i].name
    top_pile = my_deck.pile[0].name
    console.log('It\'s '+name_curr+ ' turn.')
    for (var i = 0; i < current.hand.length;i++){
      console.log(current.hand[i].name);
    }
    function play_card(){
      var ploy = prompt("Please enter card position to play: 0-N (n is number of cards)\n\nTop of pile: "+ top_pile, "Starts at zero");
      console.log(current.hand[ploy]);
```

Just below this line I can't make the element pop that I can call
    current.hand[ploy]

```
      console.log(current.hand[ploy].pop())};
    //   if(this.hand[play] == 'skip' || 'Skip'){
    //
    // }
    play_card()
    }
  }
function start_game(){
  var playernames = []
  var num_of_players = prompt("Please enter number of players", "4")
  var my_deck = new Deck()
  my_deck.shuffle()
  var x = 1
  while (x <= num_of_players){
    var player_names = prompt("Please enter player name", "shawn");
    curr_hand = []
    my_deck.deal = function(){
      return curr_hand.push(my_deck.deck.pop())}
    for(var i = 0; i<7; i++){
      my_deck.deal();
      }
    newplayer = player_names+x
    newplayer = new Player(curr_hand, player_names, newplayer);
    playernames.push(newplayer);
    x++;
    }
  my_deck.pile.push(my_deck.deck.pop())
  console.log(my_deck.deck);
  var game = new functioning_turns(playernames, my_deck)
}
start_game()
```

Comment: What does “can’t pop” mean? Is there an error?

Comment: Why don't you explain what you WANT to do and what actually happens. What do you mean by "can't"?

Comment: Current is not declared. It is an implicit global. Add `"use strict";` at the very top of your file.

Comment: Try console.log `current.hand[ploy]`. `pop()` will return `undefined` if array is empty.

Comment: Use `current.hand.splice(ploy, 1)` to delete 1 object at position ploy in array `current.hand`.

Comment: Current doesn't need to be declared, 'use strict' messes up my code

Comment: ryan if you don't know what pop() is then you dont need to be commenting

Comment: thank you originato

Comment: i console.log current hand in the line just before it and it shows the card object

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem well, you are trying to call `Array.prototype.pop()` on a string...

This works:

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

arr.pop();

console.log(arr);
```

This does not work, of course:

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

arr[1].pop(); // TypeError

console.log(arr);
```